# Need user to be able to "add an option" to a select list

Tags: php, xml, drop-down-menu, addition

Editing a form that adds a medical surgery event to a Google Calendar.  On the form is a (surgeons list) select box that pulls it's option values from the index.php file.  I'm trying to change that to enable the user to "add a surgeon" to that select box list by typing a name into a textbox then clicking a button to "add".

My solution was to add a text field and a button under the "surgeons list" select box.  Typing in a name then clicking a submit button would write the new surgeon's name to an XML file.  I was then going to have the "surgeons list" select box pull it's option values from the XML file.

I was able to create the input box and button that would add the new surgeon name to an XML file but now I have two submit buttons.  When I attempt to add that new surgeons name to the XML file, it thinks I've completed the whole form and I'm attempting to submit it.  How do I send the new option value to the XML file without submitting the form?  Any info is appreciated.

Here is the current select box (that is not pulling from the xml file yet) and my xml addition field below...

```
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="<?php if($edit) echo 'edit';else echo 'insert';?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="event_id" value="<?php if($edit) echo $event_data['id'];else echo '0';?>">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="event_title">Surgeon Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <select name="event_title" id="event_title" class="form-control required">
    <option value="BERASI"> BERASI</option>
    <option value="BERGHOFF"> BERGHOFF</option>
    <option value="BIGGS"> BIGGS</option>
    <option value="BORUS"> BORUS</option>
    <option value="BURKE"> BURKE</option>
    <option value="CANNONE"> CANNONE</option>
    <option value="DEARBORN"> DEARBORN</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <label for="surgeon" >Surgeon</label>
    <input type="text" name="surgeon" class="btn btn-secondary"/>
    <input type="submit" name="ok" value="add"/>
    </div>
    </div>
```

The current submit button on the form that my addition is clashing with is here...

```
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="<?php if($edit) echo 'edit';else echo 'insert';?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="event_id" value="<?php if($edit) echo $event_data['id'];else echo '0';?>">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="event_title">Surgeon Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <select name="event_title" id="event_title" class="form-control required">
    <option value="BERASI"> BERASI</option>
    <option value="BERGHOFF"> BERGHOFF</option>
    <option value="BIGGS"> BIGGS</option>
    <option value="BORUS"> BORUS</option>
    <option value="BURKE"> BURKE</option>
    <option value="CANNONE"> CANNONE</option>
    <option value="DEARBORN"> DEARBORN</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <label for="surgeon" >Surgeon</label>
    <input type="text" name="surgeon" class="btn btn-secondary"/>
    <input type="submit" name="ok" value="add"/>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Here is an image of my form...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDpuy.png)

Here is the Swing JSC code...

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Cursor;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
    import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.ObjectInput;
    import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
    import java.io.ObjectOutput;
    import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
    import java.net.URL;

    import javax.swing.Box;
    import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
    import javax.swing.ComboBoxModel;
    import javax.swing.JComboBox;
    import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkEvent;
    import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkListener;

    public class MemComboBoxDemo extends JFrame {

      protected MemComboBox urlComboBox = new MemComboBox();

      public MemComboBoxDemo() {
        super();
        setSize(300, 100);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        p.add(new JLabel("Address"));

        urlComboBox.load("addresses.dat");
        ComboBoxListener lst = new ComboBoxListener();
        urlComboBox.addActionListener(lst);

        MemComboAgent agent = new MemComboAgent(urlComboBox);

        p.add(urlComboBox);
        getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        WindowListener wndCloser = new WindowAdapter() {
          public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            urlComboBox.save("addresses.dat");
            System.exit(0);
          }
        };
        addWindowListener(wndCloser);

        setVisible(true);
        urlComboBox.grabFocus();
              }

      class ComboBoxListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          System.out.println( urlComboBox.getSelectedItem());
        }
      }

      public static void main(String argv[]) {
        new MemComboBoxDemo();
      }
    }

    class MemComboAgent extends KeyAdapter {
      protected JComboBox comboBox;

      protected JTextField editor;

      public MemComboAgent(JComboBox c) {
        comboBox = c;
        editor = (JTextField) c.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
        editor.addKeyListener(this);
      }

      public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        char ch = e.getKeyChar();
        if (ch == KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED || Character.isISOControl(ch))
          return;
        int pos = editor.getCaretPosition();
        String str = editor.getText();
        if (str.length() == 0)
          return;

        for (int k = 0; k < comboBox.getItemCount(); k++) {
          String item = comboBox.getItemAt(k).toString();
          if (item.startsWith(str)) {
            editor.setText(item);
            editor.setCaretPosition(item.length());
            editor.moveCaretPosition(pos);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    class MemComboBox extends JComboBox {
      public static final int MAX_MEM_LEN = 30;

      public MemComboBox() {
        super();
        setEditable(true);
      }

      public void add(String item) {
        removeItem(item);
        insertItemAt(item, 0);
        setSelectedItem(item);
        if (getItemCount() > MAX_MEM_LEN)
          removeItemAt(getItemCount() - 1);
      }

      public void load(String fName) {
        try {
          if (getItemCount() > 0)
            removeAllItems();
          File f = new File(fName);
          if (!f.exists())
            return;
          FileInputStream fStream = new FileInputStream(f);
          ObjectInput stream = new ObjectInputStream(fStream);

          Object obj = stream.readObject();
          if (obj instanceof ComboBoxModel)
            setModel((ComboBoxModel) obj);

          stream.close();
          fStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.err.println("Serialization error: " + e.toString());
        }
      }

      public void save(String fName) {
        try {
          FileOutputStream fStream = new FileOutputStream(fName);
          ObjectOutput stream = new ObjectOutputStream(fStream);

          stream.writeObject(getModel());

          stream.flush();
          stream.close();
          fStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.err.println("Serialization error: " + e.toString());
       }
      }
    }
```

Comment: The simplest way is if a user adds a new surgeon name, process this as part of your submit action (adding it to the box from then on) rather than trying to do it on-the-fly.

Comment: Would you happen to have an example i could see?  Any information is apprecaited!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Jquery would come handy in this situation. What you could do is simply check when the user click on the add Button, you go get the current value of the field, and using Javascript / Jquery you add it to your select box:

```
<input type="text" class="addingElement">
<button class="addingButton">Add</button>
<select name="event_title" id="event_title" class="form-control required">
    <option value="BERASI"> BERASI</option>
    <option value="BERGHOFF"> BERGHOFF</option>
    <option value="BIGGS"> BIGGS</option>
    <option value="BORUS"> BORUS</option>
    <option value="BURKE"> BURKE</option>
    <option value="CANNONE"> CANNONE</option>
    <option value="DEARBORN"> DEARBORN</option>
</select>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.addingButton').on('click', function(){
        var newElement = $('.addingElement').val();
        $('#event_title').append('<option></option>').attr('value', newElement).html(newElement);
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I will try to get this working this evening.  I'll let you know how it goes.  Thanks again!

Comment: You need to understand that Java and Javascript are two diffrent things. You can't use swing in JAvascript. I'll try to make a jsfiddle with the answer.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work. I'm a Creative Director so by birthright I "think" I can code :) But this is hard work for sure. I searched around the web and found this. Can I use Swing JSC in my web form? If so how would I put this into my form? It's supposed to load a combobox with options and give the user the option to add to that list - and writes it to a .dat file so others can see the updates as well. Perhaps there is another way to do this?

The example Swing JSC code is above...

Comment: Thanks Nicolas!  I'll try it now.

Comment: PERFECT!  Exactly what I needed.  Thank you!!

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Comment: Wait, one more thing Nicolas.  When the user "adds" the name to the list can I have it write or save somewhere so others can see it in the new addition in the list as well?  So that the users "add" becomes a permanent part of the list?  That possible?

Comment: Well you would have to add an Ajax call to your server to save the data in your database. this way you can get it back everytime you do your first query to get your data.

Comment: i suggest looking into ajax [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) those are pretty good tutorial on the subject

Comment: I think I could make sense of the ajax tutorial, then how do I have my combox write to the "ajax_info.txt" file?  This tutorial is just about loading from that document correct?

Comment: It's when you are adding the value to the combobox, you can send a ajax request at the same time.

Comment: Actually you don't have to save to a file, you need a PHP endpoint where you receive data and save it in a Database, just like a form in HTML

Comment: I hate to bug you with this, any chance you can write an example I can follow?

Comment: For the PHP part i can't do anythings for you, but i can add the Ajax request to the fiddle, would that works ?

Comment: That would be a HUGE help!

Comment: I'm a CD with lots of experience.  Let me know if you ever need anything  http://www.LeskoFolio.com

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o0qc8wvc/1/ there, i added the Ajax part, you would need to add some information like the url and maybe something to do with the success callback, and thanks for the info i'll take that in note :)